# How to find the generator of the following ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, generating-functions

> How to find the generator of the   following ideals
>
> 1. $\cal a=${$F\in \mathbb Q[X]:F(i)=0$} in $\mathbb Q[x]$,
> 2. $\cal b=${$F\in \mathbb Q[X]:F(\sqrt 2i)=0$} in $\mathbb Q[x]$?
> 3. $\cal c=${$F\in \mathbb R[X]:F(\sqrt 2)=0$} in $\mathbb R[x]$,
> 4. $\cal d=${$F\in \mathbb R[X]:F(i\sqrt 2)=0$} in $\mathbb R[x]$.

All I know is that I  have to find the polynomial of least degree $F(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $F(x)=0.$

### Solution(1)

By inspection, $F(x)=x^2+1$. So, $\cal a=\langle x^2+1\rangle$

### Solution(2)

By inspection, $F(x)=x^2+2$. So, $\cal b=\langle x^2+2\rangle$

### Solution(3)

By inspection, $F(x)=x^2-2$. So, $\cal c=\langle x-\sqrt 2\rangle$

### Solution(4)

By inspection, $F(x)=x^2+2$. So, $\cal d=\langle x^2+2\rangle$

Are the above solutions correct? Is there any analytic method of obtaining the generator of ideals?

Comment: Question 3 doesn't make sense. A polynomial with rational coefficients, multiplied by a real irrational, will not have rational coefficients (unless it's the zero polynomial), so you can't have an ideal in ${\bf R}[x]$ consisting of polynomials in ${\bf Q}[x]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:Apologies,i made the typo

Comment: @GerryMyerson:See the edit

Comment: Are my solutions correct?

Comment: Consider $x-\sqrt2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:Sure...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE! Here is an algebraic explanation.

Consider an ideal $I$ in $K[x]$, where $K$ is a field. Since $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, there is a polynomial $f\in K[x]$ such that $I=\langle f\rangle$.

Consider the quotient ring $K[x]/\langle f\rangle$. The polynomial $f$ has a zero in the quotient ring, namely the residue class $\bar x = x+\langle f\rangle$, since $f(\bar x) = 0$ in the residue class ring. The polynomial $f$ has smallest degree with the property $f(\overline x)=0$ and so is irreducible over $K$, i.e., the minimum polynomial of $\bar x$ over $K$.

So what you are looking for is the minimum polynomial $f\in K[x]$ of an element $a\in L$ in an extension field $L$ over $K$.

Comment: :I need to know if we start with a general polynomial $F(x)=a_0+a_1x^1+...+a_nx^n$,then is there any approach by which we automatically land on the generating function?

Comment: That's exactly what Wuestenfux is giving you, Damon.